# How to remove UWP (Cordova) title bar arrow?

Tags: javascript, windows, cordova, uwp

I have a Cordova application running on Windows 10 (UWP) and I am using Visual Studio 2017 to build the Cordova project.

The hosted window has an arrow in the title bar that I am trying to remove.

Here is a picture of what I am talking about:

[image: UWP Cordova App with Title Bar Arrow]

I saw another question on StackOverflow that had an accepted answer to use the following code:

```js
if (cordova.platformId == "windows")
{
    var currentView = Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
    currentView.appViewBackButtonVisibility = Windows.UI.Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
}
```

However, this does not work for me.

I perform the check after DeviceReady and the cordova.platformId does indeed equal "windows" which is fine.

How does the JavaScript code execute the Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManger namespace? I understand it is a UWP namespace as per the following link,
 [Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.core.systemnavigationmanager), but where is this defined and accessible by the JavaScript code? Is there a 3rd party Cordova plugin I am missing?

Comment: Check the official code:[navigator.js](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/6370138b150ca8a34ff86de376ab6408c5587f5d/Samples/FeedReader/js/js/navigator.js#L138)

Comment: @Macer are you solve your? issue Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  I was able to fix it by putting the following code in the render of my first component:

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.platformId === "windows")
{
    console.log("Disabling back button")
    var currentView = window.Windows.UI.Core.SystemNavigationManager.getForCurrentView();
    currentView.appViewBackButtonVisibility = window.Windows.UI.Core.AppViewBackButtonVisibility.collapsed;
}
```